# OpenVPN modify client names broadcasted

Tags: openvpn

For my use case, I am looking to identify different devices connected to the private VPN. I am setting up an OpenVPN server with one certificate/key for multiple devices to be connected to our server. I know the security limitations but this is just a secondary troubleshooting option so we can ssh into remote clients.

The issue is I have a Variable on the local client `clientID`, I need a way for my server to know that other than assigning it an IP address. I could not find an option to dynamically send Client-ID to the server. The only option I know is when I am generating a `common-name=example.com`, in the certificate, but i only have one certificate so it does not fit my purpose.

Does anyone know where I can add this configuration, so when a network is established my OpenVPN server will know the name on establishing a connection?

Answer (score 0):

To any one wondering the same thing,

This is for security purposes, You can generate multiple certificates and have different names or use a common certificate and make the common name change dynamically by assigning it on the client. (you can also leave the common name same but it would be hard to distinguish the different devices connected to the server)